# real time server/client application in C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, raspberry-pi, real-time

I have a working chat -server application in C++ on a raspberry pi that listens for clients and sends messages from one client to the others and vice versa using pthreads in for loops. I am using C# as the clients.

The C# clients are sending and receiving data (single byte) to the RPi server continuously, and logging the times when they send and receive data.

Looking at the logged times, I can see that there is a delay of 100 ms or so between when one client sends and the second one receives the data. This kind of delay is unacceptable for my application. I need to get it under 15 ms consistently.

In my C++ program, the time delay between receiving and sending the byte back to the client is 1-2 ms.

I am not sure if there is a problem in how I have coded the C# clients or the C++ server. I upgraded my kernel with the RT PREEMPT patch but this has not affected the delay times.

If I put in a random delay on the order of seconds before sending a byte to the server in the C# program, then the delay times improve significantly - down to 1-2 ms.

Is there a way to optimize it so even when sending continuously, the delay times are very small? I can post the codes if needed.

**EDIT: Here is the server side code on the RPi.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h> // memset
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
using namespace std;    

int BACKLOG;
#define IP_ADDR "192.168.137.99"
#define PORT "8888"
#define MAXLEN 1
#define MY_PRIORITY (49) /* we use 49 as the PRREMPT_RT use 50
                            as the priority of kernel tasklets
                            and interrupt handler by default */

#define MAX_SAFE_STACK (8*1024) /* The maximum stack size which is
                                   guaranteed safe to access without
                                   faulting */

#define NSEC_PER_SEC    (1000000000) /* The number of nsecs per sec. */
static unsigned int cli_count = 0;

vector<int> cliarray;
vector<vector<unsigned long long> > data;
pthread_attr_t custom_sched_attr;
int fifo_max_prio, fifo_min_prio;
struct sched_param fifo_param;

void stack_prefault(void) {

        unsigned char dummy[MAX_SAFE_STACK];

        memset(dummy, 0, MAX_SAFE_STACK);
        return;
}


void send_message(char *s, int sock){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<BACKLOG;i++){
        if(cliarray[i]){
            if(cliarray[i] != sock){
                send(cliarray[i], s, 1,0);
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Send message to all clients */
void send_message_all(char *s){
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<BACKLOG;k++){
        if(cliarray[k]){
            send(cliarray[k], s, 1,0);
        }
    }
}



void *handle_conn(void *pnewsock)
{
  int sock = *(int*)pnewsock;


  char client_msg[MAXLEN];

  int read_size;
  struct timeval tv;
  bool looprun = true;
  int clientint;
  vector<unsigned long long> row(4);
  while(looprun ){   


     read_size = recv(sock, client_msg, 1, 0);
     gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

      unsigned long long milliseconds_recv =(unsigned long long)(tv.tv_sec) * 1000 +(unsigned long long)(tv.tv_usec) / 1000;

     clientint = int(*client_msg);



     client_msg[read_size] = '\0';
     /*  cout << "length of client message: " << strlen(client_msg) << endl;
       cout << "# bytes is : " << read_size << endl;     
      cout << clientint << " received" << endl;*/


    send_message(client_msg,sock);
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    unsigned long long milliseconds_sent =(unsigned long long)(tv.tv_sec) * 1000 +(unsigned long long)(tv.tv_usec) / 1000;



   row = {clientint, milliseconds_recv, milliseconds_sent, strlen(client_msg)};
   data.push_back(row);


     if (clientint == 100)
      {
        looprun = false;


        break;
      }

  }
  cout << "exit handle -conn " << endl;

  pthread_exit(NULL);

}
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{ 

        struct timespec t;
        struct sched_param param;
        int interval = 50000; /* 50us*/

        /* Declare ourself as a real time task */

        param.sched_priority = MY_PRIORITY;
        if(sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &param) == -1) {
                perror("sched_setscheduler failed");
                exit(-1);
        }

        /* Lock memory */

        if(mlockall(MCL_CURRENT|MCL_FUTURE) == -1) {
                perror("mlockall failed");
                exit(-2);
        }

        /* Pre-fault our stack */

        stack_prefault();
    int connfd =0, n = 0;
    int *new_sock, sock;



    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int reuseaddr = 1; // True 

    // Get the address info 
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    if (getaddrinfo(IP_ADDR, PORT, &hints, &res) != 0) {
        perror("getaddrinfo");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        //return 1; 
    }

    // Create the socket 
    sock = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (sock == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
       // return 1;
    }

    // Enable the socket to reuse the address 
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseaddr, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        ::close(sock);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        //shutdown(sock,2);
       // return 1;
    }

    // Bind to the address 
    if (bind(sock, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        ::close(sock);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        //shutdown(sock,2);
        //return 0;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    // Listen 
    if (listen(sock, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
       // return 0;
    }
    cout << "Enter # clients: " ;
    cin >> BACKLOG;
     cout << "Enter name of text file (num clients - trial #).txt:" << endl;
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;
    cout << "listening for connections" << endl;
    // Main loop 

    // Main loop 
    bool running = true;
    // Initialize clients 
    while (running)
    {  
      size_t size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
      struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
      int clilen = sizeof(their_addr);
      int newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&their_addr, &size);
      if (newsock == -1) 
      {
        perror("accept");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
       // return -1;
      }
      cli_count++;
      printf("Got a connection from %s on port %d\n", inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr), htons(their_addr.sin_port));
      cliarray.push_back(newsock);
      if (cli_count == BACKLOG)
      {
         cout << "Max clients reached" << endl;
        running = false;
        break;
      }
    }

     ofstream frout("/home/pi/cplus/"+filename,ios::app);
     frout << "recv \t" << "time recv (ms) \t" << "time sent (ms) \t" << "length of msg" << endl;

    /* Send message to all clients that server is ready to accept data */  

    char r = char(cli_count);

    char *mesg = &r;

    send_message_all(mesg);

    cout << "length of mesg: " << strlen(mesg) << endl;
    //pthread_t from_ard_t, *ptr;
    pthread_attr_init(&custom_sched_attr);
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&custom_sched_attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&custom_sched_attr, SCHED_FIFO);
    fifo_max_prio = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
    fifo_param.sched_priority = fifo_max_prio;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&custom_sched_attr, &fifo_param);
    pthread_t *ptr;
    ptr =static_cast<pthread_t*>(malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*cli_count));


    int i;
    for (i=0;i<BACKLOG;i++)
    {
      if (pthread_create(&ptr[i], &custom_sched_attr, handle_conn, (void *)&cliarray[i]) != 0)//was newsock
          {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }

    /*if (pthread_create(&from_ard_t, NULL, from_ard, NULL)!=0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread\n");
    }*/

    //pthread_join(from_ard_t, NULL);
    cout << "Created threads" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < BACKLOG; i++)
    {
       pthread_join(ptr[i], NULL);
    }
    cout << "joined send/recv threads" << endl; 


    close(sock);

   /* array for timestamp data */
   int numrows = data.size();

    for (int k = 0; k < numrows; k++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            frout << data[k][j] << "\t";
        }
        frout << endl;
    }



}
```

C# client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
//make command line possible to save time info in file

namespace sockclient_cs
{

    public class Program
    {
        private System.Object lockThis = new System.Object();
        const int MAXLEN = 1;
        public bool recvrun = true;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        public NetworkStream stream;
        string fnrecv;
        string fnsend;
        public int clicount;
        DateTime centuryBegin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        Random rndseed;
        public Program(NetworkStream streamer, int clinum, string pathsend, string pathrecv, Random rand)
        {
            stream = streamer;
            clicount = clinum;
            fnrecv = pathrecv;
            fnsend = pathsend;
            rndseed = rand;

        }


        public void SendData()
        {
            int[] numarray = new int[] { 70, 80, 90, 100, 60, 50, 40, 30}; // coressponds to %, A, P, _, d
            bool looprun = true;

            while (looprun)
            {            

                int rnd1 = rndseed.Next(0, numarray.Length);
                byte[] writebyte = new byte[] { BitConverter.GetBytes(numarray[rnd1])[0] };


               int delay = rndseed.Next(2000,6000);

                Thread.Sleep(delay);

                Array.Reverse(writebyte);



                stream.Write(writebyte, 0, writebyte.Length);
                DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
                long elapsedTicks = currentDate.Ticks - centuryBegin.Ticks;
                Decimal milliseconds = elapsedTicks / (Decimal)TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fnsend))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(numarray[rnd1] + "\t" + milliseconds + "\n");

                }


                Console.Write("sent: " + numarray[rnd1] + "\n");
                if (numarray[rnd1] == 100)
                {
                    looprun = false;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        public void ReceiveData()
        {
            bool recvrun = true;
            int numenders = 0;
            while (recvrun)
            {

                String responseData = String.Empty;
                byte[] bb = new byte[1]; //1 byte of data coming in
                ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
                int bytes;

                    bytes = stream.Read(bb, 0, bb.Length);

                DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
                long elapsedTicks = currentDate.Ticks - centuryBegin.Ticks;
                Decimal milliseconds = elapsedTicks / (Decimal)TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
                int numback = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { bb[0], 0x00 }, 0);
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fnrecv))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(numback + "\t" + milliseconds + "\n");

                }

                //responseData = ascii.GetString(bb, 0, bytes);






                    Console.WriteLine("Received: " + bb[0] + "\n");
                    if (numback == 100)
                    {
                        numenders++;
                        if (numenders == clicount-1)
                        {
                            recvrun = false;
                            break;
                        }

                    }







            }
            Console.Write("Exiting receive");
        }
    }
    public class Simple
    {


        public static void Main()
        {

            Console.Write("Enter name of recv data file (ex. cli1recv_1.txt):\n");
            string recvfile = Console.ReadLine();
            string pathrecv = @"C:\Users\Neha\Documents\Ayaz Research\" + recvfile;
            Console.Write("Enter name of send data file (ex. cli4send_1.txt):\n");
            string sendfile = Console.ReadLine();
            string pathsend = @"C:\Users\Neha\Documents\Ayaz Research\" + sendfile;

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(pathrecv))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Received \t Recv time (ms) \n");

            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(pathsend))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Sent \t Sent time (ms) \n");

            }
            //SerialPort Serial1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            Random seed = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
            try
            {


                TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting...");
                tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.137.99", 8888); //address of RPi on arbitrary non privileged port
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                NetworkStream stream = tcpclnt.GetStream();

                /*Receive the welcome from server */
                String responseData = String.Empty;
                Byte[] bb = new byte[2]; //1 byte of data coming in
                ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
                int bytes = stream.Read(bb, 0, bb.Length);

                int numback = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { bb[0], 0x00 }, 0);
                Console.Write("Received initial message from server: " + bb[0] + "\n");


                /*byte[] writebyte = new byte[] { BitConverter.GetBytes(82)[0] };

                Console.Write("writebyte length is " + writebyte.Length + "\n");
                Array.Reverse(writebyte);
                stream.Write(writebyte, 0, writebyte.Length);



                bytes = stream.Read(bb, 0,bb.Length);
                // convert to string info 
                Console.Write("reading byte length is " + bb.Length + "\n");

                responseData = ascii.GetString(bb, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("bb[0] is: " + bb[0] + "and bb[1] is: " + bb[1] + "\n");
                int numback = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { bb[0], 0x00 }, 0);

                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + responseData +  "\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + numback + "\n");*/

                Program clientObject = new Program(stream,numback,pathsend, pathrecv, seed);
                //non loop format - for cppserv

                ThreadStart sending = new ThreadStart(clientObject.SendData);
                Thread sendThread = new Thread(sending);
                sendThread.Start();

                ThreadStart receiving = new ThreadStart(clientObject.ReceiveData);
                Thread recvThread = new Thread(receiving);
                recvThread.Start();

                sendThread.Join();
                recvThread.Join();

                tcpclnt.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error...." + e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is what Client 2 is sending to Client 1 and the timestamp.

```
Sent     Sent time (ms) 

70  1467720189893.1576

80  1467720189912.1587

60  1467720189926.1595

60  1467720189937.1602

50  1467720189949.1608

60  1467720189959.1614

40  1467720189969.162

100 1467720190006.1641
```

Here is what Client 1 is receiving from Client 2 and the timestamp.

```
Received     Recv time (ms) 

70  1467720190016.1647

80  1467720190063.1674

60  1467720190079.1683

60  1467720190109.17

50  1467720190126.171

60  1467720190137.1716

40  1467720190149.1723

100 1467720190161.173
```

Comment: How are these devices connected? And how are you sending data right now? Over TCP/IP? Or UART?

Comment: To be clear, Client A sends a message to the server, which relays it to Client B? And it takes 100 ms for B to receive after A sends? You're using TCP/IP? Datagrams? It's hard to say what might be going on without seeing the code for sending and receiving on client and server.

Comment: The delay could be coming from anywhere. What is the network delay? Are you sure the logs aren't lying to you? Are you sure you're interpreting the logs correctly? Can you post them here so we could make the same determination? What does your code look like? Have you performed network tests to verify the network between your devices? Have you tried swapping out the RPi? I've written C# apps that talk over a couple switches and achieve sub-millisecond latency. The problem isn't computational delay.

Comment: Also, if your clients are running on different machines, are you sure the machine times are synchronized?

Comment: I am using TCP. I posted the logs and codes as an edit. The clients are running on the same machine; I am launching the same C# program twice.

Comment: @JimMischel yes Client A sends to server which relays the message to Client B. The same is done for Client B to Client A simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the [Nagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) algorithm at the sender

```
Socket.NoDelay = true
```

Comment: I switched to UDP and I am seeing the same strange delay in the timing on the C# client side (I switched to using the stopwatch class). When I run Wireshark at the same time to capture the network packets, it doesn't show any huge delays. Everything is under 2 ms or so. It leads me to suspect that there is still some error in the timing mechanism I've implemented, but I have no idea how to rectify the issue.